# Is it possible to schedule a local notification after getting push notification in objective C in all app states?

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

My requirement is: whenever we get a silent push notification from server, app schedule a local notification after 30 min.

Is it possible in every app state? (Specially when app killed)

If YES, I need to write some different code of notification or can I use the same I am using to schedule the local notification?

My code is:

```c
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))
completionHandler
{
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = currentTime + 30min;
    localNotification.alertBody = alertMessage;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.repeatInterval = repeatInterval;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not in every app state. Since you set your local notification at `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and that method is only fired when app is either running OR it's in background. If your app is killed or in other words it's not running or not in background, that method won't be triggered. And in that case you won't be able to set up a local notification when app is killed.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)